# Logarithmic matrix equation

Tags: matrices

I would like to know how to solve algebraicly the equation $A^n = B$. I have no back-history, but the univariable $a^n = b$ has the logarithm $n = \log_a^b$ as solution. The variable is $n$ in this case.

I thank you in advance.

Comment: THe variable is $n$ for the equation. The solution you gave also fits, but in other situation.

Comment: The first question to consider is "what do you mean by $A^n$ when $n$ is not an integer (and maybe not a real number)?"

Comment: THe question posed, what then?